# Remove a given product attribute for variations from existing woocommerce products

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I can't seem to find anyone dealing with this exact situation, nor can I quite work it out myself.

In my situation, I have several hundred products that have an attribute, let's call it foo. In the `wp_term_taxonomy` table its `taxonomy` is `pa_foo`. It might have three possible values: `big`,`bigger`,`biggest`. There is also one other attribute, `bar`, with different values. I want to keep those.

Now, I know I can remove the taxonomy stuff like so:

```sql
    DELETE FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE count < 5 AND taxonomy = 'pa_foo');
    DELETE FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE count < 5 AND taxonomy = 'pa_foo';
    DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id NOT IN (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy);
```

but on the product display page, I am still seeing the dropdown listing `big`, `bigger`, and `biggest`. How do I get rid of that pesky thing? I want woocommerce to either get rid of or completely ignore that `foo` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It will not be possible to do it with a SQL query** as the related attribute data for variable products is also stored inside a serialized array in `wp_postmeta` table within `meta_key = '_product_attributes'` *(and maybe `meta_key = '_default_attributes'`…)*

Additionally removing a product attribute used for variations, will oblige you to remove all related product variations for the variable product…

Comment: I was afraid of that being the case. The longer I work with woocommerce (and wordpress in an ecommerce setting), the less I like it.